# How to get the biggest number in a file?

Tags: performance, bash, sorting

I want to get the maximum number in a file, where numbers are integers that can occur in any place of the file.

I thought about doing the following:

```
grep -o '[-0-9]*' myfile | sort -rn | head -1
```

This uses `grep` to get all the integers from the file, outputting one per line. Then, `sort` sorts them and `head` prints the very first one.

But then thought that `sort -r` may cause some overhead, so I went for:

```
grep -o '[-0-9]*' myfile | sort -n | tail -1
```

To see what is fastest, I created a huge file with some random data, such like this:

```
$ cat a
hello 123 how are you i am fine 42342234 and blab bla bla 
and 3624 is another number
but this is not enough for -23 234245
$ for i in {1..50000}; do cat a >> myfile ; done
```

So that the file contains 150K lines.

Now I compare the performance in my `GNU bash version 4.2` and `sys` is way smaller for `sort -rn`:

```
$ time grep -o '[-0-9]*' myfile | sort -n | tail -1
42342234

real    0m1.823s
user    0m1.865s
sys 0m0.045s

$ cp myfile myfile2    #to prevent using cached info
$ time grep -o '[-0-9]*' myfile2 | sort -rn | head -1
42342234

real    0m1.864s
user    0m1.926s
sys 0m0.027s
```

So I have two questions here:

- What is best, `sort -r | tail -1` or `sort -rn | head -1`?
- Is there a fastest way to get the maximum integer in a given file?

---

---

#### Testing the solutions

So I ran all the commands and compared the time it gets them to find the value. To make things more reliable, I created a bigger file, 10 times bigger than the one I mentioned in the question:

```
$ cat a
hello 123 how are you i am fine 42342234 and blab bla bla 
and 3624 is another number
but this is not enough for -23 234245
$ time awk -v s="$(cat a)" 'BEGIN{for (i=1;i<=500000;i++) print s}' > myfile
$ wc myfile 
1500000 13000000 62000000 myfile
```

Benchmark, from which I see [hek2mgl's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30592354/1983854) is the fastest:

```
$ time awk 'NR==1 || max < 0+$0 {max=0+$0} END {print max}' RS='[[:space:]]+' myfile
42342234

real    0m3.979s
user    0m3.970s
sys 0m0.007s
$ time awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(int($i)){a[$i]=$i}}END{x=asort(a);print a[x]}' myfile 
42342234

real    0m2.203s
user    0m2.196s
sys 0m0.006s
$ time awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){m=(m<$i)?$i:m}}END{print m}' RS='$' FPAT='-{0,1}[0-9]+' myfile
42342234

real    0m0.926s
user    0m0.848s
sys 0m0.077s
$ time tr ' ' '\n' < myfile | sort -rn | head -1
42342234

real    0m11.089s
user    0m11.049s
sys 0m0.086s
$ time perl -MList::Util=max -lane '$m = max $m, map {0+$_} @F} END {print $max' myfile


real    0m6.166s
user    0m6.146s
sys 0m0.011s
```

Comment: Another option that could be quite quick: `awk -v RS="[^-0-9]+" '$0>max{max=$0}END{print max}' myfile`.

Comment: I checked this one and it is quite fast also, @TomFenech Don't know what is best here, to add it into hek2mgl's answer, to keep it here in comments or you adding a new answer with it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @EdMorton numbers are always surrounded by either spaces or beginning / end of line. Does it clarify my statement? Now that you mention this case, maybe the `grep` could be like this: `grep -oE '\b-?[0-9]+'`. Although I guess some corner cases can still appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure a C implementation optimized using assembler will be the fastest. Also I could think of a program which separates the file into multiple chunks and maps every chunk onto a single processor core, and afterwards just get's the maximum of nproc remaning numbers.

Just using the existing command line tools, have you tried `awk`?

```
time awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){m=(m<$i)?$i:m}}END{print m}' RS='$' FPAT='-{0,1}[0-9]+' myfile
```

Looks like it can do the job in ~50% of the time compared to the perl command in the accepted answer:

```
time perl -MList::Util=max -0777 -nE 'say max /-?\d+/g' myfile
cp myfile myfile2

time awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){m=(m<$i)?$i:m}}END{print m}' RS='$' FPAT='-{0,1}[0-9]+' myfile2
```

Gave me:

```
42342234

real    0m0.360s
user    0m0.340s
sys 0m0.020s
42342234

real    0m0.193s   <-- Good job awk! You are the winner.
user    0m0.185s
sys 0m0.008s
```

Comment: This is quite a nice answer and I am astonished: I wouldn't have thought that `awk` would do it faster than standard commands like `sort` and `tail/head` (probably it is `grep` what consumes most of the time).

Comment: I would say it is the `sort` command that comsumes the most time, at least approximately the same as `grep`.. That are simply more iterations than with `awk`.

Comment: I just ran `time grep -o '[-0-9]*' myfile  &>/dev/null` and it takes `real 0m1.534s, user 0m1.530s, sys 0m0.001s`!!

Comment: @fedorqui Why are you surprised?  What `awk` does is `O(N)`, while `sort` is `O(N log(N))`.

Comment: @lcd047 However, sort does not operate on the same amount of lines. However you are right, it's the number of iterations which makes the difference here.

Comment: I don't understand your record separator: a space or an asterisk? Did you want `RS='[^[:digit:]-]+'` instead?

Comment: @glennjackman This was basically typo. It should have been `[[:space:]]+`. But I wrote that in a moment where I still thought that the files contains numbers only separated by spaces. The error didn't popped up, since `int("foobar")` will evaluate to `0`. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Many thanks for your interesting approach, hek! You are a master on how to handle `RS`, I have a lot to learn from you :) Finally, Glenn's was the fastest solution.

Comment: You are welcome @fedorqui. It was a fun! And .. (drum roll) we have a new champion!! `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){m=(m<$i)?$i:m}}END{print m}' RS='$' FPAT='[0-9]+' myfile` . The `FPAT` I've learned from EdMorten - the master of everything in awk :)

Comment: The `FPAT` is actually not correct since it doesn't handle negative numbers.. Will refine it after work. Will also add a benchmark to compare it to Glenn's answer. (I did, of course. It takes ~50% of the perl solution)

Comment: @fedorqui Updated it. We have a new champion! :)

Comment: Huh, my timings: perl 0.657s real, gawk 0.981s real

Comment: I could reproduce that results on my desktop at work again and again. I'm now at home. Let me try it here.

Comment: @glennjackman At home perl 0.945 , awk 0.414. Have you used the same `myfile` as in the question?

Comment: No, I was using my file of a million random positive integers.

Comment: The difference is interesting. But we should all use the same file for benchmark. (or present times for different myfiles) Note that I'm back in ~2.5hours.. Need to hurry...

Comment: @glennjackman Your results are really misleading since you changed the input data and with that the problem itself. Having your input data, the `rand` file, I would use `awk '{m=(m<$0)?$0:m}END{print m}'` which takes ~33% of the perl solution. (0.910 perl, 0.342 awk).. perl takes way more for that - which is not suprising at the end since perl does way more things. Btw, `sort -n rand | tail -n1` took `0.275`

Comment: `awk 'm<$0{m=$0}END{print m}' rand` is a bit faster than the awk command in my last comment. It took `0.313`.

Answer (score 3):

In awk you can say:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(int($i)){a[$i]=$i}}END{x=asort(a);print a[x]}' file
```

#### Explanation

In my experience awk is the fastest text processing language for most tasks and the only thing I have seen of comparable speed (on Linux systems) are programs written in C/C++.

In the code above using minimal functions and commands will allow for faster execution.

```
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) - Loops through fields on the line. Using the default FS/RS and looping
                     this way is usually faster than using custom ones as awk is optimised 
                     to use the default

if(int($i))        - Checks if the field is not equal to zero and as strings are set to zero 
                     by int, does not execute the next block if the field is a string. I 
                     believe this is the quickest way to perform this check

{a[$i]=$i}         - Sets an array variable with the number as key and value. This means 
                     there will only be as many array variables as there are numbers in 
                     the file and will hopefully be quicker than a comparison of every 
                     number 

END{x=asort(a)     - At the end of the file, use asort on the array and store the s
                     size of the array in x.

print a[x]         - Print the last element in the array.
```

---

#### Benchmark

Mine:

```
time awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(int($i)){a[$i]=$i}}END{x=asort(a);print a[x]}' file
```

took

```
real    0m0.434s
user    0m0.357s
sys     0m0.008s
```

---

**[hek2mgl's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30592354/1983854)**:

```
awk '{m=(m<$0 && int($0))?$0:m}END{print m}' RS='[[:space:]*]' file
```

took

```
real    0m1.256s
user    0m1.134s
sys     0m0.019s
```

For those wondering why it is faster it is due to using the default FS and RS which awk is optimised for using

Changing

```
awk '{m=(m<$0 && int($0))?$0:m}END{print m}' RS='[[:space:]*]'
```

to

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)m=(m<$i && int($i))?$i:m}END{print m}'
```

provides the time

```
real    0m0.574s
user    0m0.497s
sys     0m0.011s
```

Which is still a little slower than my command.

I believe the slight difference that is still present is due to `asort()` only working on around 6 numbers as they are only saved once in the array.

In comparison, the other command is performing a comparison on every single number in the file which will be more computationally expensive.

I think they would be around the same speed if all the numbers in the file were unique.

---

**[Tom Fenech's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592249/how-to-get-the-biggest-number-in-a-file#comment49254644_30592249)**:

```
 time awk -v RS="[^-0-9]+" '$0>max{max=$0}END{print max}' myfile

 real    0m0.716s
 user    0m0.612s
 sys     0m0.013s
```

A drawback of this approach, though, is that if all the numbers are below zero then max will be blank.

---

**[Glenn Jackman's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30596592/4923629)**:

```
time awk 'NR==1 || max < 0+$0 {max=0+$0} END {print max}' RS='[[:space:]]+' file

real    0m1.492s
user    0m1.258s
sys     0m0.022s
```

and

```
time perl -MList::Util=max -0777 -nE 'say max /-?\d+/g' file

real    0m0.790s
user    0m0.686s
sys     0m0.034s
```

The good thing about `perl -MList::Util=max -0777 -nE 'say max /-?\d+/g'` is that it is the only answer on here that will work if 0 appears in the file as the largest number and also works if all numbers are negative.

---

#### Notes

All times are representative of the average of 3 tests

Comment: You missed to add "benchmarked on a Pentium 2" :D Can you show the results of `wc -l file`?

Comment: No need to delete. If you document how your code works and update the benchmark, it is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: I can confirm that it is faster than my attempt. I really wonder why atm... Still have not enough time to investigate...

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful explanation and attention to detail. Get a big +1. I will wait some hours to accept an answer, so that more people may go through the post and suggest other solutions. I also want to compare your approach with [Tom Fenech's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592249/how-to-get-the-biggest-number-in-a-file#comment49253614_30592249) to see which one performs better.

Comment: You can save a cycle or two: from `if(int($i)){a[$i]=$i}` to `a[0+$i]=0+$i` -- force the value to be considered a number by adding it to zero.

Comment: @glennjackman Just tried that, seems to take longer? Maybe from assignments even when it's not a number ?

Comment: @glennjackman that would cause awk to evaluate `0+$i` twice and assign to `a` for every string in the input file, while the original only affects `a` for integers.

Comment: So I did test all the solutions and the fastest one was @glennjackman 's. Thanks a lot for your comprehensive answer, benchmark and everything. Will check how can I also draw attention to this :)

Comment: @fedorqui No problem :) Weird that Glenns answer was quickest for you, mine was for me. Which version of awk and perl are you using and was it on the original file you proposed ?

Comment: I am using `perl 5.14.2` and `GNU Awk 4.1.0`.

Comment: @fedorqui Ahh right, I'm on `perl 5.10.0` and `GNU Awk 3.1.8`, maybe perl got quicker or awk got slower.

Comment: @fedorqui Just downloaded perl 5.22.0 and GNU Awk 4.1.2 and got the same result with awk being faster. Really weird, I wonder what is making the difference??

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised by awk's speed here. perl is usually pretty speedy, but:

```
$ for ((i=0; i<1000000; i++)); do echo $RANDOM; done > rand

$ time awk 'NR==1 || max < 0+$0 {max=0+$0} END {print max}' RS='[[:space:]]+' rand
32767

real    0m0.890s
user    0m0.887s
sys 0m0.003s

$ time perl -MList::Util=max -lane '$m = max $m, map {0+$_} @F} END {print $max' rand 
32767

real    0m1.110s
user    0m1.107s
sys 0m0.002s
```

---

I think I've found a winner: With perl, slurp the file as a single string, find the (possibly negative) integers, and take the max:

```
$ time perl -MList::Util=max -0777 -nE 'say max /-?\d+/g' rand
32767

real    0m0.565s
user    0m0.539s
sys 0m0.025s
```

Takes a little more "sys" time, but less real time.

Works with a file with only negative numbers too:

```
$ cat file
hello -42 world
$ perl -MList::Util=max -0777 -nE 'say max /-?\d+/g' file
-42
```

Comment: Also this will never print negative numbers if there is a non number in the file.

Comment: `>|` is a redirection operator that overrides bash's `noclobber` shell option. Not needed here.

Comment: Found an awk solution which is almost 50% faster than the perl attempt. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30592354/171318 :)

Comment: What does the `-E` flag do? It appears to allow the use of say, but i can't find any documentation that includes it in the list of flags ?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this will be fastest:

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' < file | sort -rn | head -1
42342234
```

Third run:

```
$ time tr ' ' '\n' < file | sort -rn | head -1
42342234
real    0m0.078s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.076s
```

btw DON'T WRITE SHELL LOOPS to manipulate text, even if it's creating sample input files:

```
$ time awk -v s="$(cat a)" 'BEGIN{for (i=1;i<=50000;i++) print s}' > myfile

real    0m0.109s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.061s

$ wc -l myfile
150000 myfile
```

compared to the shell loop suggested in the question:

```
$ time for i in {1..50000}; do cat a >> myfile2 ; done

real    26m38.771s
user    1m44.765s
sys     17m9.837s

$ wc -l myfile2
150000 myfile2
```

---

If we want something that more robustly handles input files that contain digits in strings that are not integers, we need something like this:

```
$ cat b
hello 123 how are you i am fine 42342234 and blab bla bla
and 3624 is another number
but this is not enough for -23 234245
73 starts a line
avoid these: 3.14 or 4-5 or $15 or 2:30 or 05/12/2015

$ grep -o -E '(^| )[-]?[0-9]+( |$)' b | sort -rn
 42342234
 3624
 123
73
 -23

$ time awk -v s="$(cat b)" 'BEGIN{for (i=1;i<=50000;i++) print s}' > myfileB
real    0m0.109s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.076s

$ wc -l myfileB
250000 myfileB

$ time grep -o -E '(^| )-?[0-9]+( |$)' myfileB | sort -rn | head -1 | tr -d ' '
42342234
real    0m2.480s
user    0m2.509s
sys     0m0.108s
```

Note that the input file has more lines than the original and with this input the above robust grep solution is actually faster than the original I posted at the start of this question:

```
$ time tr ' ' '\n' < myfileB | sort -rn | head -1
42342234
real    0m4.836s
user    0m4.445s
sys     0m0.277s
```

Comment: Interesting, based on [your edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30600902/revisions) I also was checking what is fastest, `sort -rn | head -1` or `sort -n | tail -1`.

Comment: Yeah looks like it doesn't matter [much] if you use the tail or head approach. I thought there might be a saving with head since it could stop reading after the first line.

Comment: What if there was a word like 100n and 99 was the largest number, sort -n would show 100n as the largest(it does on mac at least which is all i have to test on atm).

Comment: @user using `int()` in awk as you do in your answer would treat it the same way, i.e. as `100`. If there are "hard" cases to be considered/discounted (e.g. what if `3.5` was in the input - that's not an integer but it is a number) then the OP needs to show/discuss them in his question.

Comment: Oh yeah! I'll sort my answer out :) sort -n also counts characters as being bigger than minus numbers so if the largest number was less than 0 it would show a word instead.

Comment: @User112638726 yes, you're right. fedorqui - is that a possibility in your input?

Comment: I considered the basic case here, just integers (no float numbers) and appearing "alone" (no "100n" or similar). Of course, having all negatives is a possibility. More conditions would lead to a more generic solution but slower, but it is not the case here. Maybe in the future I will ask something related but taking these things into consideration. Also, good catch with the creation of `myfile`. To me, `for i in ...` wasn't that slow (one minute or so), but still it is good to keep remembering what you always tell and use `awk` even for this.

Comment: I finally accepted Glenn Jackman's answer, since his Perl script is the fastest to me. To me, the `tr` approach was three times slower than the awk's. Many thanks for the investigation here and always!