# Use awk to find regex of variable length and edit following lines based on length found

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, fastq

I am trying to edit a fastq-file with awk.

```
@someheader example fastq file
TGTACTTAGAGAAGCGC
+
BDDADHHIHHHIICHIG
@nextheader
CCGTAACCTGGGCAGTG
+
DDDDDHIIIIIIIIIII
```

What I want to achieve is:

- look for the following regex: /AGATCGGAAG[ATGC]{0,24}$/ - if possible only in lines where its actually possible to find (e.g. line 2, 6, 10, x+2%4=0 basically)
- If found, remove the match
- Then remove the same number of characters at the end 2 lines after the current line

So far, editing one line based on the regex was no problem for me, i used:

```
awk '{ gsub(/AGATCGGAAG[ATGC]{0,24}$/, ""); print RLENGTH }'
```

But I have no idea how i can achieve deleting the same number of characters 2 lines later.
I am very unexperienced and only started learning about awk, so any help is welcome.

greetings

EDIT: heres an example containing the pattern above

```
@HWI-ST558:329:H3K2GBCXX:1:1101:5408:2985 1:N:0:ATCACG
CCTCCCGGTCGGTGCTGAGAGAGACTGGGCTCTCTGGAACTCCACCACCGAGATCGGAAGAG
+
HHHIIIIHDHIIIHIIGHHHIHFHHCHHIE?GHHGHF?GECFEEHFHHHCHDHHHFEEHHHH
```

this should be the output:

```
@HWI-ST558:329:H3K2GBCXX:1:1101:5408:2985 1:N:0:ATCACG
CCTCCCGGTCGGTGCTGAGAGAGACTGGGCTCTCTGGAACTCCACCACCG
+
HHHIIIIHDHIIIHIIGHHHIHFHHCHHIE?GHHGHF?GECFEEHFHHHC
```

the file contains 40 million of these entries, with ~250k containing the pattern

Comment: Please show some sample data that actually contains the pattern.

Comment: Perhaps the match function will help.  It sets RSTART and RLENGTH to the beginning index and length of the part of a string that matches some regular expression.  RLENGTH will tell you how many characters matched, and you can save it in a variable:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work but since your sample input doesn't contain any lines that'd match the regexp and you didn't provide any expected output, of course it's untested:

```
NR%4 == 2 { match($0,/AGATCGGAAG[ATGC]{0,24}$/) }
RSTART && (NR%4 ~ /^[02]$/) { $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) }
{ print }
```

Comment: I asked a question about finding the maximum number in a file and there is some discussion about the best way to do it with `awk`. It would be great to have your expertise looking at it! http://stackoverflow.com/q/30592249/

Comment: Wont RSTART be reset when the next line doesn't match and so won't be set for 2 lines after ? If not then won't this remove the start of every second line. Finally modulus 4 can never be 4 so this bit `NR%4 ~ /^[24]` doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @User112638726 Changed [24] to [02]. Untested == untested. RSTART will only be set/cleared when NR%4 is 2, without putting too much thought into it that seems right to me. Again, though, untested.

Comment: Thanks, this works and did exactly what i was looking for. Could you explain your statement a bit more in detail since i would like to learn! @ed morton

Comment: @voiDnyx look up the various constructs (NR, match, RSTART, substr) in the man page (e.g. http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) and see if you can figure some of it out and I'll be happy to answer specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $length;
while (<>) {                            # Read line by line.
    if (2 == $. % 4) {
        $length = length $1 if s/(TAGAGA[ACTG]{0,7})$//;
    } elsif (0 == $. % 4 && $length) {  # We should shorten this line.
        s/.{$length}$//;
        undef $length;                  # Done.
    }
    print;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit long, but it should work:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        n=-1
        pat="AGATCGGAAG[ATGC]{0,24}$"
    }
    NR%4==2 && $0 ~ pat {
        match($0, pat);
        gsub(pat, "");
        n=NR+2;
    }
    NR==n {
        print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        next
    }
    { print }

'
```