# Bash script to add numbers from all files (each containing an integer) in a directory

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have many .txt files in a directory. Each file has only an integer. 
How to write a bash script to add these integers and save the output to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop through the files extracting its integers and then sum them:

```
grep -ho '[0-9]*' files* | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

#### Explanation

- `grep -ho '[0-9]*' files*` extract numbers from the files whose name matches `files*`. We use `-h` to prevent getting the file name of the match and `-o` to just get the match, not the whole line.
- `awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'` loop through the values coming from `grep` and sum them. Finally, print the result.

#### Test

```
$ tail a*
==> a1 <==
hello 23 asd
asdfasfd

==> a2 <==
asdfasfd
is 15

==> a3 <==

$ grep -ho '[0-9]*' a* | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
38
```

Comment: I will try tomorrow to add some variants coming from the great set of results I got in [How to get the biggest number in a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30592249/1983854)

Answer (score 0):

You can `cat` your files and then sum up using `awk`:

```
cat *.txt | awk '{x+=$0}END{print x}' > test.txt
```

test.txt should contain the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Create some test files:

```
$ for f in {a,b,c,d}.txt; do
>   echo $RANDOM > "$f"
> done

$ cat *.txt
18419
25511
31919
28810
```

Sum it using Bash:

```
$ i=0; 
$ for f in *.txt; do 
>   ((i+=$(<"$f")));
> done
$ echo $i
104659
```