# How to count all numbers in a file with awk?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I want to count all numbers that are in a file.

Example:

```
input -> Hi, this is 25 ...
input -> Lalala 21 or 29 what is ... 79?
```

The output should be the sum of all numbers: `154` (that is, 25+21+29+79).

Answer (score 4):

From this [beautiful answer by hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30592354/1983854) on how to extract the biggest number in a file, let's catch all the numbers in the file and sum them:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){sum+=$i}}END{print sum}' RS='$' FPAT='-{0,1}[0-9]+' file
154
```

This sets the record separator in a way that the whole block of text is a unique record. Then, it sets [`FPAT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/User_002dmodified.html) so that every single number (positive or negative) is a different field:

> FPAT #
>
> A regular expression (as a string) that tells gawk to create the
>   fields based on text that matches the regular expression. Assigning a
>   value to FPAT overrides the use of FS and FIELDWIDTHS for field
>   splitting.

Comment: Can I ask you another question about awk? (:

Comment: @MikeJames yep, but it is probably worth [asking another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat data
Hi, this is 25 ...
Lalala 21 or 29 what is ... 79?
$ grep -oP '\b\d+\b' data | paste -s -d '+' | bc
154
```

Answer (score 1):

With `grep` and `awk` :

```
$ cat test.txt
Hi, this is 25 ...
Lalala 21 or 29 what is ... 79?
$ grep '[0-9]\+' -o test.txt | awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
154
```

Comment: Don't do that. `grep` can't do anything `awk` can't.