# find maximum number in row string and show two column - linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed, scripting, grep

I want to find maximum number in the strings inside file

already i have a script to get maximum number

```
counters_2016080822.log:2016-08-08 15:55:00,10.26.x.x,SERVER@10.26.x.x,SSCM_VRC/sscm-vrc-flow-20160602,,transactions.tps,13
counters_2016080823.log:2016-08-08 23:00:00,10.26.x.x,SERVER@10.26.x.x,SSCM_VRC/sscm-vrc-flow-20160602,,transactions.tps,14
counters_2016080823.log:2016-08-08 23:05:00,10.26.x.x,SERVER@10.26.x.1x,SSCM_VRC/sscm-vrc-flow-20160602,,transactions.tps,19
```

firstly by putting last column which is number to new .txt file
using sed

```
sed 's/^.*tps,//'
```

13

14

19

then sorting and getting first row

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]+' myfile.txt | sort -rn | head -n 1
```

**19**

but now i want to find maximum then get maximum number and it is time 
(date & time or just time)

as below:

> 23:05:00 19

Comment: StackOverflow is not a 'Code this for me'-site. Try for yourself and ask questions about a specific problem in your code.

Comment: Related: [How to get the biggest number in a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30592249/1983854)

Comment: @Tom ,I just asked to related command or trick not as you said "'Code this for me'" 

. thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
echo "counters_2016080822.log:2016-08-08 15:55:00,10.26.x.x,SERVER@10.26.x.x,SSCM_VRC/sscm-vrc-flow-20160602,,transactions.tps,13
counters_2016080823.log:2016-08-08 23:00:00,10.26.x.x,SERVER@10.26.x.x,SSCM_VRC/sscm-vrc-flow-20160602,,transactions.tps,14
counters_2016080823.log:2016-08-08 23:05:00,10.26.x.x,SERVER@10.26.x.1x,SSCM_VRC/sscm-vrc-flow-20160602,,transactions.tps,19" | \
sed -r 's/^.*:([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}),.*,([0-9]+)$/\1 \2/' | \
sort -n -k 3 -t ' ' | tail -n 1
```

Comment: used this one ,by awk file2.txt ____
cat file1.txt | sed -r 's/^.*:([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}),.*,([0-9]+)$/\1 \2/' | sort -n -k 3 -t ' ' | tail -n 1 > file2.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use only awk:

time and max:

```
awk -F, '$NF > max {max=$NF; time=$1}; END{ print substr(time,(length(time)-7))" "max}' myfile.txt
```

date,time and max:

```
awk -F, '$NF > max {max=$NF; time=$1}; END{ print substr(time,(length(time)-18))" "max}' myfile.txt
```

F : Input field separator variable
NF :gives you the total number of fields in a record,

or with awk and cut

this is time and max

```
awk -F, '$NF > max {max=$NF; time=$1}; END{ print time" "max}' myfile.txt | cut -d' ' -f2,3
```

this is date, time and max

```
awk -F, '$NF > max {max=$NF; time=$1}; END{ print time" "max}' myfile.txt | cut -d: -f2-
```

Comment: When doing min or max calculations always seed them with the first value read, don't pick some arbitrary number (0 if you don't choose anything) and hope that some of the input will be greater or smaller than that number.

Comment: the result is maximum value but not max time.

Answer (score 0):

here is another solution

```
$ awk -F'[ ,]' '{print $2,$NF}' file | sort -k2nr | head -1

23:05:00 19
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'[ ,]' 'NR==1{m=$NF} $NF>=m{m=$NF; t=$2} END{print t, m}' file
23:05:00 19
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @TobySpeight No, it's perfectly clear as-is. Don't bother replying to this comment.